# Where is pip's setting file in linux system?

Tags: python

I'm using python3 in both Windows and WSL(Windows subsystem Linux).

I don't understand why, but my network does not allow SSL certification. So when I try to install some python packages in my VENV,

I always type below sentence

```
pip install package_names --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

I'm sick about everytime typing it. So I found alternative ways.

In fule "VENV/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/ssession.py",
there is a option about SSL.

[image]

If I disable this option, No more need to type that sentences.

I can find this session.py file in windows python venv, But I cannot find in Linux python venv.

Where can I find it?

Comment: Disabling SSL verification like that is a terrible idea. Why do you need `--trusted-host` In the first place?

Comment: @AKX i already mentioned about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your pip.conf file(s) for the pip instance you wish.

```
ian@local % pip config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading '/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/Users/ian/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/Users/ian/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/pip.conf'
```

Edit the pip.conf that matches your scenario to include the trusted host-

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
```

You should be good to go.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it changes global pip conf unlike windows. i want only affect in each venvs. but i dont think that option is exist